# How can I organise this matrix in beamer?

Tags: beamer, matrices

I have three vectors that should be in same line in this frame. I can not do it. Could you help me. 
The MWE is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Identification}
\begin{itemize}
\item  Identification scheme: \citet{Christiano.etal2005}
\[
    Y_{t}=\left[Y_{1t}, MP_{t} , Y_{2t}\right]^{\prime}
\]

\[Y_{1t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
GDP \\ 
cmp  \\ 
P%
\end{array}\right]
\]; \[MP_{t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
i \\ 
M2%
\end{array}\right]
\]; 
\[Y_{2t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
RER \\ 
SP   
\end{array}\right]
\]
\item where $Y_{1t}$ represents a subset of variables that...;
\item $MP_{t}$ is the monetary..;
\item $Y_{2t}$ represents a subset...
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want the vector Y1, MP and Y2 in same line, and not as it appear in this image.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this??  Rather than starting a new equation for each vector, I just separate them with a semicolon and a `\quad`, within a line of a single equation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\citet#1{#1}
\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Identification}
\begin{itemize}
\item  Identification scheme: \citet{Christiano.etal2005}
\[
    Y_{t}=\left[Y_{1t}, MP_{t} , Y_{2t}\right]^{\prime}
\]

\[Y_{1t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
GDP \\ 
cmp  \\ 
P%
\end{array}\right]
~;\quad MP_{t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
i \\ 
M2%
\end{array}\right]
~;\quad
Y_{2t}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
RER \\ 
SP   
\end{array}\right]
\]
\item where $Y_{1t}$ represents a subset of variables that...;
\item $MP_{t}$ is the monetary..;
\item $Y_{2t}$ represents a subset...
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gilson These are _slides_, they do not need be precise. Just drop the semicolon completely, or at least, don't put that stupid space in front of them.

Comment: @tohecz "Stupid" is no doubt a value judgement.  My editors require equation punctuation.  I hate punctuation of my equations, but to satisfy the editors, I prefer to offset it as the compromise.  So don't insult gilson, insult me.

Comment: Sorry , I addressed Gilson so that you both receive the notification. The punctuation is necessary , but the space is spurious and distracting . Punctuation always follows the preceding text without any space in western typography . ( The only exceptions are opening parentheses and apostrophes , and the colon if you're French . )

Comment: @tohecz I am well acquainted with the rules of punctuation.  I just consider equations to be a "special use case", since equations themselves can contain commas (`u_{i,j}`) and periods (`3.1`) as part of the equation, in which trailing punctuation can lead to confusion.  Just imagine an equation ending in `u_i` and then requiring a comma as the following punctuation.  It might be confusing to the reader.  Or how about an equation ending the sentence with the integer "3". Oops, now we have an immediate period, that might convey the notion of real-ness rather than integer-ness.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've had trillions of such equations. And another thing: will you follow the same rules if the equation were inline?

Comment: @tohecz I have been known to add a thin space following an inline equation that precedes punctuation, if I perceive a possible source of confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18051/discussion-between-tohecz-and-steven-b-segletes).